# What data is supposed to be displayed on the Experience Profile - Profiling tab?

Tags: experience-profile

We have a Sitecore 8.1-3 instance. We have it running in production and it is recording visit information in Mongo.  We have set up Profiles and Profile Keys in the Marketing Control Panel.  However whenever we go to Experience Profile and click on a contact and then click on the Profiling tab we never see any data.  All we see is "No profile data available" - for all contacts.  Shouldn't there be data showing on this tab?  I can't seem to find any Sitecore documentation that explains what should be showing up on this tab and also how to configure Sitecore properly so that data shows up here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The **Profiling** tab displays data connected to the user profiles / pattern cards / personas, which you should define in the CMS.

Please, refer to the "Profiling" section of the documentation: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/personalization/insession_personalization/content_profiles

Answer (score 0):

In order for the **Profiling** tab to populate, you need to assign scoring on profile cards and pattern cards. Setting up profile keys alone will not result in profile(s) being assigned to your contacts.